# Creating MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have faced syntax error during creating MySQL Trigger.

```
Create Trigger Count_McNum
before insert on tension
for each row
declare rowcount int ;
set rowcount = (select count(McNum) from tension where median is null) ;
if (rowcount >1000) 
then 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning:  rowcount> 1000!';
    END IF;
End
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'declare rowcount int' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the small keyword `BEGIN`. And as you have multiple statements, you have to change the delimiter.

```
DELIMITER $$
Create Trigger Count_McNum
before insert on tension
for each row
BEGIN
declare rowcount int ;
set rowcount = (select count(McNum) from tension where median is null) ;
if (rowcount >1000) 
then 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning:  rowcount> 1000!';
    END IF;
End$$
DELIMITER ;
```